# Is there any way to download a AzureArtifacts without PAT(personalaccesstoken)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact org.kobil.keycloak:keycloak:jar:9.0.0 from/to  (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com//_packaging/k/maven/v1): Transfer failed for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com//_packaging/k/maven/v1/org/kobil/keycloak/keycloak-core/9.0.0/keycloak-9.0.0.jar 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]

Comment: How are you trying to download it?

Comment: Trying to download using pom, have added the package as dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a feed with project scope, (Project with public visibility) able to download the published package without PersonalAccessToken.

[image]